# Navbar Collapse Toggle Won't Turn Off (after switching from bootstrap v4 beta to v4 alpha 6)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So my navbar was working great until I switched over to v4 alpha 6 to get something working with responsive utilities that the alpha had.

The page: https://kianrafiee.github.io/unity/

Before, you would see all the menu links in the navbar until your window was small enough for the toggle button to replace the menu.

Now after I started using v4 alpha 6 it just has the toggle button permanently with no other menu items.

I've tried inspecting and I can't figure out what I need to do. I tried starting the navbar from scratch using the documentation for v4 but its still the same. In fact my navbar is based on v4 anyway.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `navbar-toggleable-*` on your `nav` element.

```
<nav style="background-color: #e3f2fd;" class="navbar navbar-toggleable navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
```

You can see correct example in bootstrap documentation here:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

> Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-toggleable-* for
>   responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I looked at everything on the page but missed that. But for some reason now, when the collapse button appears, it shows up on the left under the brand-name. It's suppose to be on the right like in the documentation. And my code is the same as the documentation. Any idea on that?

Comment: I believe that in newest Bootstrap you can do it just by adding `navbar-toggler-right` class to that button

Comment: You rock man. I must admit I skimmed over that part as well in the doc. Seems I have to spend more time on that.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Man for some reason on mobile chrome the toggle button is positioned half way below the navbar.

Comment: This is really strange. I replaced the navbar with the one in the doc with toggler enabled and it still has the toggler off position on mobile devices(both chrome and safari mobile)

Comment: Seems to be because of being on alpha. Moving to beta fixed the problem. And I realized I can do what I want to do on beta anyway. So along with your help I am much farther ahead now thank you.